# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465 send mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendmail

I use the email account of my site `contact@monsite.com` to send smtp alert messages to the email of my users. but it still gives me this error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
```

errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}

here is my code

```
// send mail function
exports.sendMailer = (optionsTransporterMail = OptionsTransporterMail, optionsMail = OptionsMail, callback) => {
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(optionsTransporterMail);

  transporter.sendMail(optionsMail, function (err, info) {
    callback(err, info)
  });
}

sendMailer({
  service: 'mail.mywebsite.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'contact@mywebsite.com',
    pass: '12345678'
  }
}, {
  from: '"My app <contact@mywebsite.com>',
  to: user@domain.com,
  subject: "Notify",
  text: "Hello worlds",
  html: "Hello worlds"
}, (err, info) => {
  if err console.log(err);

  console.log(info)
})
```

it still gives this error

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

Comment: on which port is your service running?

Comment: Most probably noone is listening on your box on port 465.  You need a configured and running Mail Transport Agent (MTA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use `mail.mywebsite.com` in order to send an email. In those terms, you have to set up `host` value in options, because it seems like by default it uses localhost (127.0.0.1).

Please try the following code:

```
sendMailer({
  host: 'mail.mywebsite.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'contact@mywebsite.com',
    pass: '12345678'
  }
}, {
  from: '"My app <contact@mywebsite.com>',
  to: user@domain.com,
  subject: "Notify",
  text: "Hello worlds",
  html: "Hello worlds"
}, (err, info) => {
  if err console.log(err);

  console.log(info)
})
```

Comment: what should you install on the server to be able to do this? I mean the ability to send emails. I use nodemailer and I have entered the correct link as host, however it still fails.

Comment: sendmail if you're on *NIX based systems